# What do you call these types of words?

Tags: meaning

I just noticed something in a rather innocuous text that I was sending a friend. The word "Left", for instance, could mean, "Hey, have you left already?" or "Is anyone left here?". Both these meanings are completely different from each other even if they are using the same word(in this case, "left").

My question is, **"Does anyone know more of such words? And if so, is there a specific term for them?**"

Comment: [**auto-antonym** or **autantonym,** also called a **contronym** or **contranym**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) is a word with multiple meanings (senses) of which one is the reverse of another. For example, the word **cleave** can mean "to cut apart" or "to bind together".

Comment: @Kevin: I have no idea what you're getting at there. Sid here is asking about *single* words that can have different (wildly different? *opposite?*) meanings. How does that relate to *homonyms* (words having the same spelling or pronunciation but ***different meanings and origins***)? I don't suppose *Two people left the room, so there were only four people left* involves different etymologies.

Comment: Auto-Antonym was indeed what I was looking for, @Kevin

Comment: ok then, cleaned up my comments